# How do you create a many-to-required relationship to an entity with a composite primary key?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, asp.net-mvc-5, composite-primary-key

I am trying to create three entities: Products, Attributes, ProductAttributes.

```
public class Product 
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual List<ProductAttributes> Attributes { get; set; }
    // product detail properties
}

public class Attribute
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    // attribute detail properties
}

public class ProductAttribute
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public Guid ProductId { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public Guid AttributeId { get; set; }
    public double Value { get; set; }

    public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    public virtual Attribute Attribute { get; set; }
}
```

ProductAttributes are essentially a join table between Products and Attributes, and hold the value data of that attribute. Products can have any number of distinct attributes as long as there is a value for it. The navigation property `List<ProductAttributes>` in Products is essential for updating  product's attribute values, but I cannot seem to configure the relationship properly.

This is my `modelbuilder` code:

```
// Products
ToTable("Products", schema)
    .HasMany( x => x.Attributes)
    .WithRequired()
    .HasForeignKey(x => x.ProductId)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);

// Attributes
ToTable("Attributes", schema);

// ProductAttributes
ToTable("ProductAttributes", schema)
    .HasKey(x => new { x.ProductId, x.AttributeId });
```

I've tried this set-up above, using only Fluent API, using only Attributes, and no matter what a foreign key (typically like `ProductAttributes_ProductId`) is created in addition to the composite primary key, `ProductId` and `AttributeId` foreign keys on the ProductAttributes table. I've also tried making a dummy primary key for the table, but the navigation property still will not load the ProductAttributes.

Is there a way to configure a many to required relationship where only one entity has a composite key?

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a stab.

It seems to be that you don't need the ProductAttributes object, and let EF handle the relationship between Product and Attribute. So, your Product class will contain a list of Attribute, instead of ProductAttribute.

For example, when adding a Product with an existing Attribute, that Attribute instance will already exist in the database. EF should handle "knowing" what that Attribute instance is and make the appropriate updates using that relation.

Comment: The problem is the Value column, which is the whole point of the relationship. ProductA and ProductB can both have an AttributeA, but the Value for each can be different.